# .NET Framework Isolated Storage

Tags: .net, isolatedstorage

I have read .NET Framework Microsoft training course but still confused with the real understanding what Isolated Storage is. Could anyone give me any real life examples, where it is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN pretty much lists all of this in the introduction to [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx):

> Isolated storage is a data storage mechanism that provides isolation and safety by defining standardized ways of associating code with saved data. Standardization provides other benefits as well. Administrators can use tools designed to manipulate isolated storage to configure file storage space, set security policies, and delete unused data. With isolated storage, your code no longer needs unique paths to specify safe locations in the file system, and data is protected from other applications that only have isolated storage access. Hard-coded information that indicates where an application's storage area is located is unnecessary.

Is there something specific you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

It could be used to store Personalized Data, Application Setting that you do not want to store in either a Settings file like .ini or in the Registry. The Isolated Storage is a space on the harddrive that you normally dont use for storage. But now ASP.NET applications and normal Windows Applications can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Isolated Storage is, in effect, a location on the local file system that is determined using the user information and the assembly information so if you put files there then they should be fairly free from corruption due to other apps selecting the same location.

It gets around the issue of everyone deciding to use c:\todo to store to-do lists for example. There's a pretty good [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28VS.80%29.aspx) that's worth a read.